# arithmetic operation in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Why my C# code returns 0, if it must be 50 ?

```
double c = (1 / 2) * 100;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1`, `2` and `100`, in your example, are all `int` literals. In C#, integer division returns integers, and ignores the remainder. Only after calculating 1/2 (=0) and multiplying by 100 (=0) does the result get converted to `double`

```
(1.0/2) * 100
```

Would give the expected result, because now `1.0` is a `double` literal, and forces the other literals to be converted to `double`s also before the calculations are performed.

Answer (score 2):

`1 / 2 = 0`

This is integer division.

Try `1.0 / 2`, or why not `double c = 50.0` directly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this: (float)1/(float)2. 1 and 2 are integer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
double c = (1.0 / 2.0) * 100.0;
```

EDIT: Ops. The F is unnecessary. :(

Comment: Why use a type suffix of `F` to force the type to `float`, when without the suffix, the literals will be `double`, and that matches the desired final result type?

Comment: Because first you execute (1/2) that is an *integer* division that returns 0, then you multiply 0 with 100 that returns 0 again. At least  the 0 is converted to double and assigned to the variable c.

Comment: I meant the `1.0` is a double literal. `1.0F` is a float literal. Since you're going to assign to a `double`, why not make it double throughout?

Comment: @DavideAversa wrong answer try `double c = (1.2F / 2.0F) * 100.0F;` the result has to be 60 but `c` equals to `60.000002384185791`

Comment: There is always numerical noise in floating point operation. You should handle it according to your desired precision.

Answer (score 2):

**if you want an integer number to be treated as double, use the suffix d or D**

[MSDN Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Code snippet:

```
double d = (1d / 2) * 100;
```

or

```
double d = (1 / 2d) * 100;
```

or even

```
double d = (1d / 2d) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will infer the type for 1 and 2 to System.Int32, not double

```
double c = (1.0 / 2.0) * 100;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Should give you the right result

Answer (score 0):

I think you need^

```
double c = (1 / 2) * 100;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

It results: 50